# Scanf input & other questions

Tags: c, arrays, scanf, eof

I have a program that has these objectives:

1. Read input into array
2. Read until EOF
3. Record the number of successful (numeric) inputs

I start by initializing:

```
int array[200];
int size = sizeof(array)/sizeof(int);
int num_inputs = 0;
```

Then I call a function `void input(int * array, int size, int *num_inputs)`

```
input(array, size, &num_inputs);
```

_

```
    void input(int * array, int size, int *num_inputs) {

    int i = 0;

    printf("Enter numbers:\n");
    while( scanf("%d", &array[i]) != EOF ) {
        i++;
        *num_inputs++;
        if (i == (size-1))
            break;
    }
}
```

1. num_inputs doesn't work. From debugging (or what little I know about debugging), num_input goes from 0 to some random number. What am I doing wrong? Something with pointers?
2. Let's say I input `5 9 8 8 3 4` - will scanf interpret it as 6 inputs? Will num_input be 6? If not, how do I achieve that? I want to be able to write `5 6 3 6` Newline `4 9 3` and the program to be able to interpret it as writing 7 things into the array and num_input being 7.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) `*num_inputs++;` --> `++*num_inputs;` or `(*num_inputs)++;`

Comment: Note: `array[199]` is not used.  I'd expect `while(i < size && scanf("%d", &array[i]) == 1) {`

Comment: `scanf()` can return EOF however, that is not the important criteria to check.  Rather check how many of the `format specifiers` in the format string were successfully input/converted.  For the call to `scanf()` in the posted code, the returned value to check for is 1, not EOF.

Comment: the `%d` format specifier will consume leading `white space` so having the input interspersed with <newline> sequences is not a problem.

Comment: regarding this line: `*num_inputs++;`,  the precedence of operators in C, has the `++` operator at a higher level than the `*` de-reference operator.  To correct that problem use parens,  I.E. `(*num_inputs)++;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As [*@BlueMoon*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1275169/blue-moon) already mentioned, it is because you are incrementing the pointer `num_inputs`. Not the pointee `*num_inputs`.

   So, change `*num_inputs++;` to `(*num_inputs)++;` (Or use a local variable, thanks [*@BlueMoon*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1275169/blue-moon)).
2. Yes. After the above change, you will get the output you needed for both the cases.

Run and check the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void input(int * array, int size, int *num_inputs) {

    int i = 0;

    printf("Enter numbers:\n");
    while( scanf("%d", &array[i]) != EOF ) {
        i++;
        (*num_inputs)++;
        if (i == (size-1))
            break;
    }
}


int main() {
    int array[200];
    int size = sizeof(array)/sizeof(int);
    int num_inputs = 0;
    input(array, size, &num_inputs);
    printf("num_inputs: %d\n",num_inputs);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Minor: Better to use `while( scanf("%d", &array[i]) == 1) {` else code will incorrectly count  should `scanf("%d", &array[i]) != EOF` encounter non-numeric data .

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this line:

```
    *num_inputs++;
```

It deferences and returns the value and then increments the pointer, but the *pointee* is not incremented at all. It effectively invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) due to the pointer being incremented.

That's why it's always better to write *readable* code so that you don't have to worry about precedence.
Use a local variable and use it to increment in the loop and finally assign it to `*num_inputs`.

```
int count = 0;

while( scanf("%d", &array[i]) != EOF ) {
        i++;
        count++;
        if (i == (size-1))
            break;
}

*num_inputs = count;
```